# Cordova Android conflict between library versions

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, google-play-services

I'm building a cordova app that uses 2 plugins [aerogear push plugin](https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-cordova-push) and [google-maps plugin](https://github.com/n00dl3/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin).

The fact is that the google maps plugin requires

- `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0`
- `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0`

whereas the push plugin requires `com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11` so when I try to build the app, gradle complains :

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

here is the output of `gradle dependencies`:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+ -> 22.2.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1
+--- org.jboss.aerogear:aerogear-android-core:2.1.0
+--- org.jboss.aerogear:aerogear-android-pipe:2.1.0
|    +--- org.jboss.aerogear:aerogear-android-core:2.1.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2
+--- org.jboss.aerogear:aerogear-android-push:2.2.0
|    +--- org.jboss.aerogear:aerogear-android-core:2.1.0
|    +--- org.jboss.aerogear:aerogear-android-pipe:2.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 22.2.1 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0 (*)
```

extracted from `build.gradle`:

```
apply from: "org.jboss.aerogear.cordova.push/hellocordova-dependencies.gradle"
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0")
    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0")
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

I don't know how I could handle this version conflict... Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally got it, I just created the `build-extras.gradle` and tells gradle to force 7.8.0 version:

```
configurations.all{
    resolutionStrategy{
        force ("com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you place this file?

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/#extending-buildgradle